# Ocean Waves Simulation Setting

Tags: rendering, animation

i wanna make an ocean wave simulation but i stuck with couple of experiments that has bad result as shown below. what is the best setting to make it looks really good?
[image: fluid sim]

Comment: Hi :). You can try the Ocean Modifier instead. It's not a fluid sim, but can look rather good.

Comment: There are several step by step tuts like ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmeCqQgj74Y$ FlipFluid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWhPJmfLzNo ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWhPJmfLzNo ... so you would have to ask probably more specific.